# Command line to develop Android apps

Tags: android

From the official [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) now it becomes hard to find the dedicated instructions to install Android SDK and develop apps via command line instead of Android Studio.

Do you know whether the ancient reference to command line is kept alive on the site, even though Android Studio is currently promoted as the primary IDE?

Comment: Not sure about command line access to their website but you can download the sdk tools if you have already have an Android SDK installed on your PC, without using sdk manager.

Comment: android studio projects are gradle project. you can use a lot of command line commands. [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html)